# How do I install a click package on Ubuntu Touch Trojita?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email

Trojita client develop is working on 14.04 desktop. My Touch device is 14.10 r80.  How do I install a click package on my Touch device?

Answer (score 5):

It's not in the store yet, but you can download .click packages that I've been building here: http://people.ubuntu.com/~mhall119/trojita/

Then you'll need to manually copy them to your phone and install it from the commandline, here's how I did it:

```
mhall@mhall-thinkpad:~/projects/Ubuntu/sdk/trojita/click$ adb push net.flaska.trojita_0.4.1~git280-g05de2a5_armhf.click /home/phablet/Downloads/
2420 KB/s (11078920 bytes in 4.469s)

mhall@mhall-thinkpad:~/projects/Ubuntu/sdk/trojita/click$ adb shell
root@ubuntu-phablet:~# sudo -iu phablet

phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ cd ~/Downloads/

phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/Downloads$ pkcon install-local net.flaska.trojita_0.4.1~git280-g05de2a5_armhf.click
```

Comment: More generally, use `--allow-untrusted` to install any click (not just signed ones).

Comment: I've done this with a scope and it appeared to work (it said it installed), but it doesn't show up as being installed anywhere.  Any ideas, @mhall119 and others?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu UI Toolkit front-end has been forked from Trojita into a new projected called Dekko, which is available to download and install on Ubuntu phones from the store.